# Live USB: how to access USB drive that linux booted from

Tags: mount, live-usb, removable-storage

Can't find it in `/media` or `/mnt`.

What I want:

- live distro so I have guarantee it won't break and will boot/work every single time
- have access to directory on that USB drive for storage purposes, ie. use in typical pen drive fashion

What I don't want:

- persistent install
- use casper.rw, as it makes much harder/impossible to access data from other machines
- partition the drive as it makes backups/cloning harder and isn't elegant

I tried to be clever, reinserted the drive after boot, but then can't even run the terminal.

I'm using Linux Mint 13 XFCE

Answer (score 8):

To find your USB drive, first issue:

```
blkid
```

then you will see something like:

```
/dev/sdxy: LABEL="USB_DRIVE_LALBEL" UUID="USB_DRIVE_UUID" TYPE="IT'S_FILE_SYSTEM_TYPE"
```

where as /dev/sdxy is your usb drive which x={a,b,c or d} and y={1,2,3,...}

now issue:

```
mount -l|grep /dev/sdxy
```

it will show (something like):

```
/dev/sdxy on /PATH/TO/USB/MOUNT/PLACE type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,quiet,errors=remount-ro) [USB_DRIVE_LALBEL]
```

I hope this will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You can see where the device is mounted with Disk Utility, it use to be mounted in:

```
/lib/live/mount/medium
```

You can't unmount the device but you can remount it with write permission:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /lib/live/mount/medium
```

Then maybe you wont be able to drag & drop files in directory but you can do it with terminal:

```
mv file.txt /lib/live/mount/medium
```

This works for me in every live USB Linux I've used. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't find it in /media or /mnt, standard casper + AUFS mount the USB drive that holds filesystem.squashfs to `/cdrom` or `/cdrom0`, that's where you're looking for the USB key partition.

For the rest, just open some file manager, maybe Thunar, you'd see them on the left panel.

And if you re-plugin the key, it would ruin the live system.

Comment: Almost, is mounted there but read only, I need to write to files.

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /cdrom`

Comment: Remounting works for me, how come this isn't accepted as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by using the Disk utility with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

When booted into the Ubuntu live disk click on "Search your computer" at the top left and type in "Disk". Click on the "Disk" utility, and you should be able to see your USB drive plugged in. Right click on it and click "Mount".

Then click on "Search your computer" and search for "Screenshot". Use the screenshot utility to capture and save your screenshots to the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu mounts it rw at `/isodevice`

Comment: Hmm, Mint which is based on Ubuntu does not. I could use Ubuntu, but prefer Mint and in general want bit less distro specific solution.

Comment: I know you're using mint, which is why I specified that this was for Ubuntu, in case anyone else came across this question and was wondering.  But anyway, this is most certainly a distro-specific thing, because they're all different.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't the 'right way', but might work for you:

- If I understand what you want correctly (esp. that you do not want a persistent install), you could just partition the USB drive, and make a data partition.
- You can boot with the 'toram' kernel parameter - then you can unplug and re-plug safely.   Where you specify that depends on the bootloader being used, but you can try it (non-persistently) at boot time, then figure out how to make it permanent (if you're using syslinux, it will be in syslinux.cfg).

Both kinda 'kludges', but might do the trick ...